# Keep on moving towards point

Tags: actionscript-3

So I'm trying to make a basic interactive pet game in AS3 using flashpunk due to it's ability to use sprite sheets. I've got the animations down (idle and walking) and moving the "pet", but I have ran into a problem.

With my current system, I have to hold down click to keep on moving the pet towards the mouse, but I want it to move to the position where the mouse was when I clicked rather than having to hold it down.

Here's my code(the checking if mouse is released part is just so it can stop the animation):

```
    override public function update():void
    {
        trace(FP.angle(sprRocket.x, sprRocket.y, FP.world.mouseX, FP.world.mouseY))
        if (Input.mouseDown)
        {
            move(FP.world.mouseX, FP.world.mouseY)
            Moving = true
        }
        if (Input.mouseReleased)
        {
            Moving = false
        }
        if(Moving && FP.angle(sprRocket.x, sprRocket.y, FP.world.mouseX, FP.world.mouseY) < 130 && FP.angle(sprRocket.x, sprRocket.y, FP.world.mouseX, FP.world.mouseY) > 20)
        {
            sprRocket.play("WalkU")
        }
        if (Moving && FP.angle(sprRocket.x, sprRocket.y, FP.world.mouseX, FP.world.mouseY) < 350 && FP.angle(sprRocket.x, sprRocket.y, FP.world.mouseX, FP.world.mouseY) > 225)
        {
            sprRocket.play("WalkD")
        }
        if (!Moving)
        {
            sprRocket.play("Idle")
        }
        //if (FP.angle(sprRocket.x, sprRocket.y, FP.world.mouseX, FP.world.mouseY) < 130 && FP.angle(sprRocket.x, sprRocket.y, FP.world.mouseX, FP.world.mouseY) > 20)
        //{
            //sprRocket.play("WalkU")
        //}
        //else
        //{
            //sprRocket.play("IdleD")
        //}
    }

    public function move(x:int,y:int):void
    {
        var angle:int = FP.angle(sprRocket.x, sprRocket.y, x, y)
        sprRocket.x += 100 * Math.cos(angle * FP.RAD) * FP.elapsed
        sprRocket.y += 100 * Math.sin(angle * FP.RAD) * FP.elapsed
        trace(angle)
    }
```

Comment: Use Event.ENTER_FRAME or a timer. Start it in if (Input.mouseDown) and clear when user click mouse again or pet reached to its destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used flashpunks built in tween system.

I also needed to keep a constant speed rather than a total duration (10 seconds for a close point is painstakingly slow) by using the speed triangle formula (time = distance/speed) and using flashpunk's built in distance calculator (FP.distance(x1,y1,x2,y2))

Thanks for the help anyway!